# How to send and receive bytes stream between PC and DE2 board

Tags: verilog

My school project is doing edge detection on DE2 board.
I'm looking for the way to send bytes stream from PC to DE2 board, and after doing edge detection, send data out back to PC. 
Any help on general ideas?

Comment: As this is primarily about hardware I think it would be best suited to  [Electonics SE](http://electronics.stackexchange.com)

Answer (score 1):

Based on the description of the DE2 on the [Altera website](http://www.altera.co.uk/education/univ/materials/boards/de2/unv-de2-board.html) you have the following IO interfaces on the DE2 board:

- Built-in USB-Blaster for FPGA configuration
- Line In/Out, Microphone In (24-bit Audio CODEC)
- Video Out (VGA 10-bit DAC)
- Video In (NTSC/PAL/Multi-format)
- RS232
- Infrared port
- PS/2 mouse or keyboard port
- 10/100 Ethernet
- USB 2.0 (type A and type B)
- Expansion headers (two 40-pin headers)

Of these there are 3 that are probably the most suitable for your purpose:

- RS232
- 10/100 Ethernet
- USB 2.0 (type A and type B)

Which one to use depends on your bandwidth / latency requirements, reliability, what sort of software interface you need, timescales, previous experience and level of interest.

RS232 should be easy to get working, there are UARTs available on [OpenCores](http://opencores.org/) that will get you up and running but the bandwidth will be pretty awful.

Writing some RTL that communicates with the PC via Ethernet packets should be pretty straightforward if you assume the network is always reliable.  Clearly if you want it to be robust you'll need to look into adding some reliability layer like [RUDP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reliable_User_Datagram_Protocol).

Communicating via USB is probably the hardest interface from both the RTL and software end of the interface, however if you have an existing example design than you can modify to suit your purpose this might be the best option.

One other possibility worth considering is to embed a processor the [Altera NIOS II](http://www.altera.co.uk/devices/processor/nios2/ni2-index.html) in the FPGA like and let that handle the interface to your host.  You could run a full Linux instance or a bare-metal stack with a dedicated TFTP to transfer data around.  There are various examples and tutorials on the web that will help you get started.